# Can we interact with Google Devtools Application element from R?

Tags: r, rselenium

I would like t download the cookies details highlighted in the attached screen and save it the an R data frame. Is there a way to do it? Any help would be much appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X74De.png)

Answer (score 0):

This only gets you one cookie that is listed in you image, not sure how to get all of them:

```
library(rvest)
url1 <- "enter_desired_url" #enter url you want to scrape
my_session <- html_session(url1)

library(httr)
cookie <- cookies(my_session) #cookies are saved in a table
cookie
```